# Why Windows needs reboot a lot more than Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, reboot

I use both Ubuntu and Windows XP. One thing that catches my attention for a long time is the high need for reboots in Windows. Most of the time when I install a program, Windows requests to reboot system. This happens considerably more frequently than Linux.

Why is it so?

Thanks!

Comment: This is changing a bit nowadays. The new architecture used on newer versions combined with appstores (like the built-in windows store, Steam, and others) is making reboots way less frequents now. My computers usually only reboot at system updates now, keeping themselves online 24/7 most of the time.

Answer (score 16):

This is because of the architecture.

The major reason for this behavior is that [Linux doesn't lock executed files and libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196897/locking-executing-files-windows-does-linux-doesnt-why), which allows direct replacement of those files and does only require the applications to restart. For installations is the reason the package-management-systems, while in Windows every program installs *all* needed libraries (even if they're already installed, but when they are in use they are locked, which needs a restart to clear the situation) in Linux an application only references the needed packages which are installed once (and never again), reducing the overhead.

Comment: Raymond Chen had a blog entry once on the problems and dangers involved (and ultimately that the user would notice weird behavior if programs misbehaved and not following contracts); it was a conscious design decision and not so much that it can't be done in Windows.

Comment: Johannes, can you give the link?

Comment: @Joey to follow up on kolistivra comment, I can't find the article on Raymond's blog. Please add it if you have it.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't on his blog, but still findable via two clicks and a quick search for `site:blogs.msdn.con/b/oldnewthing replace file in use`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.windowsconfidential.aspx